# How to ask for permissions for a lib that doesn't provide any RequestPermission helper function?

Tags: react-native, expo, android-permissions, expo-permissions

I've read the new [Expo docs](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/permissions/) regarding asking permissions ... And It's not clear if you're facing a lib that doesn't provide an helper for permissions !

The only thing I've noticed is in this sentence :

> Most permissions are added automatically by libraries that you use in your app either with config plugins or with a package-level AndroidManifest.xml, so you **won't often** need to use android.permissions to add additional permissions.

Does this mean that we could still use the [PermissionAndroid](https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid) for some custom plugins that doesn't provide a specific `requestPermissionFunction()` as `exo-location` does ( `Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();` ) ?
Despite the warning in the front page of react native website ? ....

[image]

I'm trying to use the [react-native-wifi-p2p](https://github.com/kirillzyusko/react-native-wifi-p2p#allow-grant-permission-to-wifi-module) lib and it need those permissions :

```
"android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
"android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE",
"android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE",
"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
"android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
```

Is it even possible to use this lib with expo ?
Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: try adding "permissions" section in app.json https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Wodin from the expo team helped me on this one

The answer is : YES, we can use the PermissionAndroid from react native.

And add all the permissions in the `app.json` file at `expo.android.permissions = [...]` also.

[Link to the original answer](https://forums.expo.dev/t/react-native-expo-how-to-ask-for-permissions-for-a-lib-that-doesnt-provide-any-requestpermission-helper-function/67287/2?u=seba99)